# How to automatically install Android app on user click jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a user click event for a button on a web page.

```
$('.hr_rd_s').click(function() {    
    window.open('gift.php', '_blank');
    //automatically install Android app code goes here    
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hr_rd_s"> 
    <span id="text15" class="answer">Left</span>
</a>
```

For example, if user is on Android phone, I want the app to be automatically installed on user click event. This page would be only rendered to Android phone users.

Comment: I doubt (and really, really hope) that this is not possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Can you please give your reasons?

Comment: Because if it was possible anyone could install an android app on a phone which is browsing their website without the user agreeing to it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Can I link it to the app?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to link to the page in Google Play

Comment: There looks a loophole for Android phone and someone has been doing it please check this   http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/09/11/security-firefox-for-android-can-be-tricked-into-automatically-downloading-and-executing-malicious-code/

Answer (score 1):

You can't automatically install an Android app. That would be a huge security issue. You can link to the app in the Google Play store where the user must install it. It is also possible to link to an [Android installation file](http://www.androidpit.com/android-for-beginners-what-is-an-apk-file)

Comment: If I dowonload the APK and place it on my server. Is it possible to install it from my own server via Jquery click?

Comment: See [Linking to Your Products](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html).

Comment: You can never install anything automatically on a user. That would be a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

you might use `JavascriptInterface` to communicate between Web/PHP/HTML/Javascript and native Java. check out this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030737/android-calling-java-from-webview)

and then from code you may call `Intent` to Google Play to this app, [HOWTO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android).

it's not possible to automatically install any app without user confirmation, security reasons of course